# Try out Craft Client and Pro on multiple development URLs?

Tags: license

I'm aware that running craft locally from "craft.dev" or "ontherocks.dev" will enable you to try out the Client and Pro versions (which is a super-cool feature!) - but just wanted to ask if there are any plans to allow any domain at *.local or *.dev.

Obviously totally understand not wanting to open it up too much, but just working on a few projects under development, which is a little hard to juggle on the one domain.

Comment: I wish they'd allow `localhost/*` as all my local instances are `localhost/example.com/`. I do this for a few reasons... but mostly because I hate setting up dozens of `hosts` file entries and vhosts (although `VirtualDocumentRoot` fixes the latter). And it also ensures that the sites can run in a subdirectory if needed (I know, I know).

Comment: hmmm, along the same lines, just wondering if anyone know's if I need to buy multiple lisenses to create multiple sites on craft? If so, how do I purchase multiple lisenses?

Comment: @LarryArmstrong: Every site will automatically have a license file, whether you pay for the upgrade or not. Depending on the requirements of your site, you may or may need to pay for an upgrade. If that doesn't properly answer your question, I suggest you [**ask a new question**](http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) to get better responses.

Comment: **UPDATE:** It's now possible to try Craft Pro from _any_ non-public domain: http://pixelandtonic.com/blog/test-craft-client-pro-from-any-non-public-domain

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can always use this "super-cool feature" with sub-domains of "craft.dev" or "ontherocks.dev"! You can have as many as you want:

"craft.dev"
"pro.craft.dev"
"license.craft.dev"
"testing.craft.dev"
"is.craft.dev"
"super.craft.dev"
"cool.craft.dev"

:D

Comment: You know what - totally hadn't thought of that! What an idiot I am :)