# Craft license and develop a website locally?

Tags: license

Is there any problem with buying a Craft Client account, working on the website locally (on my pc), and when it´s done move it to the server?

Is this permitted by the license?

Answer (score 6):

Sebastian, you can always work locally "for free", using "craft.dev" as host name.

Check the FAQs here at the bottom of the pricing page https://buildwithcraft.com/pricing

MAMP PRO makes it really easy to setup custom host names, btw.

Comment: This also works with subdomains of `craft.dev` (→ [Try out Craft Client and Pro on multiple development URLs?](http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/q/4368/125)).

Comment: **UPDATE:** It's now possible to try Craft Client from _any_ non-public domain: http://pixelandtonic.com/blog/test-craft-client-pro-from-any-non-public-domain

Answer (score 5):

When you move the license to production you'll see a warning in the CP - you then have the option to transfer the license to the new domain.  See [here](http://buildwithcraft.com/help/license-transferring) for more info.

Obviously then you'll get the warning in your development environment but that's something you can live with I assume!

Answer (score 3):

Short answer is **yes, that is entirely allowed**. Great information has already been provided in [Tom's answer](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/8964/45) and [Adam's answer](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/8969/45).

If you are already certain that you'll be purchasing a Craft Client account, then you won't have to do anything special to get the site working locally. As long as the same **license key** remains in your site, any purchased upgrades will remain available to you... regardless of whether the site is running locally or on a server!

Not sure how familiar you are with this, but you may want to learn more about [multi-environment configurations](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/multi-environment-configs) in Craft. It's incredibly easy to move your website between environments without losing any rights or privileges.

You can run your site locally without any warnings as long as you're using a **dev-sounding** domain. Read this article... All of the answers you're looking for should be in here:

> [How is Craft’s license agreement enforced?](http://buildwithcraft.com/help/license-enforcement)

Answer (score 0):

Any non-public domain will do the job. Just hit Upgrade in your CP then you'll get a option to use it for free as long as you work on a non-public domain so localhost works fine.

When you transfer it to a public domain and you used Craft Pro only options you have to get a license to keep it up like you did on the dev version.